# Rewrite table cells?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Beginner here

See - http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_tablerow_cells

In this example, when change content is pressed, new content is written in the cell on the top left. Would it be possible to alter it to the top right? If so, how?

Comment: [Please consider being somewhat circumspect about w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But for the best learning experience, you should try to figure it out yourself. However, be aware that [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) is not the best place to be learning things from.

Comment: In the future, you should play around with code on your own to see how you can break it, make it work, change it, etc. We're happy to help around here, but you'll learn the most if you find things out for yourself.

Comment: Nobody's going to comment that IE **hates** it when you use `innerHTML` on a table? Really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function `changeContent()` to look something like this:

```
function changeContent() {
    var x=document.getElementById('myTable').rows[0].cells;
    x[1].innerHTML="NEW CONTENT";
}
```

Essentially you are changing the x[0].innerHTML (first cell it encounters) to x[1].innerHTML (second cell it encounters).

Answer (score 1):

change `x[0].innerHTML="NEW CONTENT";` to `x[1].innerHTML="NEW CONTENT";`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible,  remplace the x[0]  by x[1].

x is an array of each cell of the first row. So x[0] is the first cell (starting from left), etc

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the function that the button triggers:

```
function changeContent()
{
  var x=document.getElementById('myTable').rows[0].cells;
  x[0].innerHTML="NEW CONTENT";
}
```

It's called by this: `<input type="button" onclick="changeContent()" value="Change content">`

If we alter the function like so:

```
function changeContent()
{
  var x=document.getElementById('myTable').rows[2].cells;
  x[1].innerHTML="NEW CONTENT";
}
```

It will populate the bottom right cell instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line with `x[0].innerHTML="NEW CONTENT";` to `x[1].innerHTML="NEW CONTENT";`